# EXCEL Conditional Formatting: Define a row range in which to identify the highest value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel spreadsheet consisting of groups of rows.  Each row group is defined by the matching values in Column A.  For example:

```
................A....................B    
1..........Group Name 1............Data1  
2..........Group Name 1............Data2  
3..........Group Name 1............Data3  
4..........Group Name 1............Data4  
5..........Group Name 2............Data5  
6..........Group Name 2............Data6  
7..........Group Name 2............Data7  
8..........Group Name 3............Data8  
9..........Group Name 3............Data9  
10.........Group Name 4............Data10  
11.........Group Name 4............Data11  
12.........Group Name 4............Data12
```

I'd like to use Conditional Formatting to highlight the highest value in Column B within each row group, but I'm not able to determine a formula to identify the range of each row group.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admitting that column B contain numeric data you can write this formula in conditional formatting:

```
=B1=MAX(IF(A1=$A$1:$A$12;$B$1:$B$12;0))
```

depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

Comment: @CRondao--  Thanks much, but it's not working.  (BTW--You were correct to assume numeric data.)  The logic in the formula looks right, but the result is that ALL cells in column B are formatted, not just the highest value in each group.  Curiously, if I enter the formula into Column C cells, it returns the highest value from ALL of Column B.  Stranger still, if I display the Function Arguments for MAX formula, it shows the correct result for each group, but the cell still displays the MAX value for ALL of Column B instead of the group.  (And, yes, I had to change the semi-colons to commas.)

Comment: I got it now.  It has to be entered as an array formula, which requires pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter (instead of just Enter) after entering the formula in the cell.  It's working perfectly.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you right, it is an array formula, in a cell you must use Ctrl Shift Enter, but, in Conditional Formatting you don't need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a standard (non-array) formula that produces a similar pseudo-MAXIF() functionality.

=$B1=MAX(INDEX($B$1:$B$12*($A$1:$A$12=$A1),,))

I typically lock the columns in a CF rule where the rows are allowed to 'float' but this is not absolutely necessary if you are applying the CF rule to a single column.